# Restrict the chance to delete a booking just more than x hours before departure in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want users not to be able to cancel a booking just 2 hours before departure time. 
I don't know where can I write this restriction. Should I write it in the model or in the controller application?

This is the pseudo-code I wrote so far:

```
class CancelValidator < ActiveMOdel::Validator  
  def validate(record)
    if record.date_trip.to_time < Date.now + 2
      record.errors[:base] << 'error'
    end
  end 
end
```

EDIT: This is all the code, but it still lets me destroy the booking.. why?

```
class CountValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
def validate(record)
        if (record.second || record.first)
        record.errors[:base]<< ' error '
        end 
end 
end

class DepartureValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

def validate(record)
        if  record.date_trip.to_date < Date.today
        record.errors[:base]<< ' error '
        end 
end 

end 

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with DepartureValidator
  validates_with CountValidator
  before_destroy :ensure_deletable

  belongs_to :dep ,:class_name => 'Stop', :foreign_key => 'dep_id'
  belongs_to :arr ,:class_name => 'Stop',:foreign_key => 'arr_id'
  belongs_to :route
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :CountStop, :to => :route, prefix: true, :allow_nil => false
  delegate :city ,:to => :arr, :allow_nil => false
  delegate :city ,:to => :dep, :allow_nil => false

def division 
  return Reservation.select{|r| r.route_id == route_id && r.date_trip == date_trip }
end

def second
        if (class_point == 2)
        y=division.select{ |l| l.class_point == 2 }.count
        if(y+1 > route.train.second_class_seats)
                return true
        end
        end
        return false
end
def first
        if (class_point == 1)
        y=division.select{ |l| l.class_point == 1 }.count
        if(y+1 > route.train.prima_classe_seats)
                return true
        end
        end
        return false
end

def ensure_deletable
  self.date_trip.to_time < Time.now + 2
end 

end
```

Comment: Well. How you mark a booking as cancel ? If you have a flag column in the booking table, then validation is the perfect choice, because before saving you can run the `valid?` method, and it will work for you..

Comment: well, to cancel a booking I usually click on the button Delete :D I didn't understand what you're saying, can you make an example please?

Comment: I meant how you mark a booking as `cancel` ? Do you delete the booking from the table? Exactly what happen when you click on `delete` ?

Comment: Yeah I delete the booking form the database

Comment: Well, then don't need the validation. Inside the controller do the check and if it condition is false, don't do the delete and return an alert to user

Answer (score 0):

Since you delete the value, you're going to want to add a [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) instead.

The benefit of this is that, before you go and delete the entity, you can decide to stop it outright if it fails your condition.

Here's an example below.  Caution:  this is untested, but this should give you the gist of things.

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :ensure_deletable

  private
  def ensure_deletable
    self.date_trip.to_time < Date.now + 2
  end
end
```

Remember, from the documentation:

> The method reference callbacks work by specifying a **protected or private method** available in the object...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Makoto! Should I put this code in the model 'booking' ?

Comment: Sorry, my hands were on overdrive there.  Yes, this should go in the entity that you're deleting.

Comment: Arre you sure that this isn't have to be put in the Controller folder? Because 'before_destroy' is undefined in the Model one.

Comment: Don't forget to add `:prepend => true` if your model has children with the `:dependent => :destroy` flag set. [Rails Guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Comment: @Pino `before_destroy` is a call back built in to Rails models. Before it executes your `destroy` method, it will run the `before_destroy` method, and this is how you hook in to that. Your controllers should never have this fine grained level of information. Their job is to facilitate the view, not be in charge of domain objects.

Comment: I edited the question with the whole model code..the application still lets me destroy the booking

Comment: @Pino:  I'm more hoping that you're not going to copy this code into your application wholesale, and that you're going to use it more as a reference on how to approach these things.  I mentioned above that this code is untested, but that is the principle behind how these callbacks work.